# Regular expression for valid filename

Tags: c#, regex

I already gone through some question in StackOverflow regarding this but nothing helped much in my case.

I want to restrict the user to provide a filename that should contain only alphanumeric characters, `-`, `_`, `.` and space.

I'm not good in regular expressions and so far I came up with this `^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]$`. Can somebody help me?

Comment: And chinense or arabic names?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This is the correct expression:

```
string regex = @"^[\w\-. ]+$";
```

`\w` is equivalent of `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`.

Comment: Of the different scenarios I tested this worked perfect, thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the '.' be escaped? Docs for '.' say "Matches any single character except \n"

Comment: @bitwise '.' doesn't need to be escaped when it appears in a character class.

Comment: `\w` is only equivalent in english dictionaries, so it should be `^[0-9a-zA-Z_\-. ]+$` instead

Comment: This removes valid characters such as $

Comment: A filename should not starts with a space, so @"^[\w\-.][\w\-. ]*$" may be a little better.

Comment: Regex `[^0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+` gives me proper sanitized file name

Comment: The proposed RegEx allows a filename such as . or .. - which is obviously not a valid filename in any OS that I know. There's a much better solution (currently down below) by @Johny Skovdal

Answer (score 36):

To validate a file name i would suggest using the function provided by C# rather than regex

```
if (filename.IndexOfAny(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) != -1)
{
}
```

Comment: OP wants to limit the valid characters.

Comment: You mean as and when the user types the chars for the file name? even then we can subscribe for the keydown or key press event and make a check and avoid having that character from becoming a part in the file name

Comment: If it must be regex I would build this regex with GetInvalidFileNameChars.    ^[^/:\*\?<>\|]*$  => everything allowed without invalidfilenamechars

Comment: In the docs, it says "The array returned from this method is not guaranteed to contain the complete set of characters that are invalid in file and directory names.". This would make this technique a little risky. It's safer to use an inclusive list, rather than exclusive list.

Comment: What might be valid file names on a local system, might not be valid file names in all the systems it is supposed to be represented, e.g. database columns in VARCHAR, URLs etc. So not having to tackle it later, more restrictive naming at first, might be a go to strategy.

Answer (score 19):

While what the OP asks is close to what the currently accepted answer uses (`^[\w\-. ]+$`), there might be others seeing this question who has even more specific constraints.

First off, running on a non-US/GB machine, `\w` will allow a wide range of unwanted characters from foreign languages, according to the limitations of the OP.

Secondly, if the file extension is included in the name, this allows all sorts of weird looking, though valid, filenames like `file .txt` or `file...txt`.

Thirdly, if you're simply uploading the files to your file system, you might want a blacklist of files and/or extensions like these:

> web.config, hosts, .gitignore, httpd.conf, .htaccess

However, that is considerably out of scope for this question; it would require all sorts of info about the setup for good guidance on security issues. I thought I should raise the matter none the less.

So for a solution where the user can input the full file name, I would go with something like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$
```

It ensures that only the English alphabet is used, no beginning or trailing spaces, and ensures the use of a file extension with at least 1 in length and no whitespace.

I've tested this on [Regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/EJcjiu/3), but for future reference, this was my "test-suite":

```
## THE BELOW SHOULD MATCH
web.config
httpd.conf
test.txt
1.1
my long file name.txt

## THE BELOW SHOULD NOT MATCH - THOUGH VALID
æøå.txt
hosts
.gitignore
.htaccess
```

Answer (score 15):

In case someone else needs to validate filenames (including Windows reserved words and such), here's a full expression:
`\A(?!(?:COM[0-9]|CON|LPT[0-9]|NUL|PRN|AUX|com[0-9]|con|lpt[0-9]|nul|prn|aux)|[\s\.])[^\\\/:*"?<>|]{1,254}\z`

Extended expression (don't allow filenames starting with 2 dots, don't allow filenames ending in dots or whitespace):

`\A(?!(?:COM[0-9]|CON|LPT[0-9]|NUL|PRN|AUX|com[0-9]|con|lpt[0-9]|nul|prn|aux)|\s|[\.]{2,})[^\\\/:*"?<>|]{1,254}(?<![\s\.])\z`

Edit:
For the interested, here's a link to Windows file naming conventions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That looks about right... where did you find the "reserved characters and words"? ... there's a section called that on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename... and where did you find the other bits and pieces?  Maybe you could just add a link, for interest?

Comment: This pattern matches null.txt which is a ok filename. Here's a tweaked version: \A(?!(?:COM[0-9]|CON|LPT[0-9]|NUL|PRN|AUX|com[0-9]|con|lpt[0-9]|nul|prn|aux)(\.|\z)|\s|[\.]{2,})[^\\\/:*"?<>|]{1,254}(?<![\s\.])\z

Comment: @AndreasZita Nice catch. I know that Windows has problems with NUL.txt for example: http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx_aux_c.html

Answer (score 3):

use this regular expression `^[a-zA-Z0-9._ -]+$`

Comment: juergen d, `^[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]+$` but filename can contain dot

Comment: `string regex = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\.-_ ]+$"`

Comment: ш understood what you meant, dot in `[]` doesn't mean any symbol, it's dot

Comment: -1 , as `[.-_]` is a short version of `./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`

Comment: @Mark It will match `<`,`>`,`=`,`@`, etc... characters also. You may try those.

Comment: @Engineer you are wrong. The dot is literally in square brackets. Why would it not, because then you could simply write the dot without any square brackets. It would not make sense. burning_LEGION also told you this. See here: http://regexr.com/3acim

Comment: @modiX Do you ever seen regexps like `[a-z]`? it means all alphabetical lowercase symbols, doesn't it? Same situation is for `[.-_]` regexp. It means all symbols , which has charcode above `.`(dot)s charcode and below `_`(underscore) charcode. Write script, to loop symbols from `.` to `_` and you will see `/0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^` result. So `[.-_]` regexp matches all those symbols

Comment: @modiX PS: burninglegion just corrected his answer. My comment was related to his/her first answer, which you can see from his/her edits.

Comment: @Engineer Alright my bad, now I got your point about `[.-_]`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For full character set (Unicode) use
`^[\p{L}0-9_\-.~]+$`

or perhaps
`^[\p{L}\p{N}_\-.~]+$`
would be more accurate if we are talking about Unicode.

I added a '~' simply because I have some files using that character.

You can expand upon this to allow Unicode characters with accent marks as well:

`^([\p{L}\p{N}\-_.~]|\P{M}\p{M}*)+$`

The Mark category was separated out to force that an accent mark MUST be preceded with a non-accent point. Please read [Unicode Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) for details.

Comment: Though this does NOT have the OP required restrictions, it is a great solution for validating filenames on just about any OS and language.

Answer (score 2):

This is a minor change to Engineers answer.

```
string regex = @"^[\w\- ]+[\w\-. ]*$"
```

This will block `".txt"` which isn't valid.

Trouble is, it does block `"..txt"` which is valid

Comment: ".txt" is a perfectly valid, if not odd, filename in windows. Likewise, "foo.bar.baz" is valid, but this won't work with that either. The OP doesn't put any specific "looks sane" requirements on.

Answer (score 1):

I've just created this. It prevents two dots and dot at end and beginning. It doesn't allow any two dots though.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\.(?!\.)([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5})(?<!\.)$
```

Answer (score 1):

When used in HTML5 via `pattern`:

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Export Configuration</legend>
    <label for="file-name">File Name</label>
    <input type="text" required pattern="^[\w\-. ]+$" id="file-name" name="file_name"/>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit">Export Settings</button>
</form>
```

This will validate against all valid file names.  You can remove `required` to prevent the native HTML5 validation.

Answer (score 0):

I may be saying something stupid here, but it seems to me that these answers aren't correct.  Firstly, are we talking Linux or Windows here (or another OS)?

Secondly, in Windows it is (I believe) perfectly legitimate to include a "$" in a filename, not to mention Unicode in general. It certainly seems possible.

I tried to get a definitive source on this... and ending up at the [Wikip Filename page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename): in particular the section "Reserved characters and words" seems relevant: and these are, clearly, a list of things which you are NOT allowed to put in.

I'm in the Java world. And I naturally assumed that Apache Commons would have something like `validateFilename`, maybe in `FilenameUtils`... but it appears not (if it had done, this would still be potentially useful to C# programmers, as the code is usually pretty easy to understand, and could therefore be translated). I did do an experiment, though, using the method `normalize`: to my disappointment it allowed perfectly invalid characters (?, etc.) to "pass".

The part of the Wikip Filename page referenced above shows that this question depends on the OS you're using... but it should be possible to concoct some simple regex for Linux and Windows at least.

Then I found a Java way (at least):

```
Path path = java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault().getPath( 'bobb??::mouse.blip' );
```

output:

> java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char  at index 4:
>   bobb??::mouse.blip

... presumably different `FileSystem` objects will have different validation rules

Answer (score -3):

Copied from @Engineer for future reference as the dot was not escaped (as it should) in the most voted answer.

This is the correct expression:

```
string regex = @"^[\w\-\. ]+$";
```

Comment: that is simply incorrect. :) It should not when included into character groups. There's a lot of implicit escaping mechanisms in character groups, and. e.g. `+` and `*` does not need to be escaped either: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: \w also gives different legal values depending on the current character set