# sed replace filename starts with quote

Tags: regex, linux, string, replace, sed

I have in the file strings like `img src="../image/popup.jpg"` , or `bg: 'images/xxx/popup.png'`. I would like to replace the entire filepath/name with another string with sed , I tried

```
sed 's/^"[^\s]*/somethingelse/g'
```

Comment: I only know about the filename, ,but the path needs to be matched by regex

Comment: Can you just replace the double quotes with single quotes globally?  Filenames are hard because they can contain escaped quotes.  If this is html then you may be better off using an html parser.  Or sub images/xxx with somethingelse..  Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794144/regular-expression-for-valid-filename

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,

```
 sed 's|/some/UNIX/path|/a/new/path|g' files
```

Answer (score 0):

When using sed to substitute pathnames, changing its default demiliter helps, as noted by Skynet, and judicious use of single quotes allows variable interpolation like this:

```
> a="\"hello/bye\""
> b="\"one/two\""
> echo $a
"hello/bye"
> echo $b
"one/two"
> echo $a|sed -e 's|'$a'|'$b'|'
"one/two"
```

From http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed sed does not support POSIX. 2 basic regular expressions "completely because of performance problems", however it comes close. According to http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html, one of the rules of POSIX regexes is "Using a backslash to escape a character that is never a metacharacter is an error." Since double and single quotes are not metacharacters, they should not be backslashed in POSIX regexes according to this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` with BRE:

```
sed "s/\([\"']\)[^\"']*\([\"']\)/\1somethingelse\2/g" file
```

With ERE:

```
sed -r "s/([\"'])[^\"']*([\"'])/\1somethingelse\2/g" file
```

Assumed there's no escaped quote in filename, i.e no quote inside `"..."` and `'...'`