# How to use File::Temp::tempfile with selected characters, such as digits only

Tags: regex, perl

I am using `File::Temp` library to create temporary files, like this:

```
use File::Temp  qw/tempfile/;
use Time::HiRes qw/gettimeofday/;

($_, my $tmp) = tempfile(sprintf("%d_XXXXXX", int(gettimeofday * 1000)), 
                  DIR => $directory, 
                  SUFFIX => '.pdf', 
                  OPEN => 1
                );

chmod(((stat $_)[2] & 0777) | 0644, $_);
close $_;
```

Is there an option or some easy way to force the library to use just selected characters, such as digits, for the `XXXXXX` name part? Is it possible to use **regex** to define such allowed characters?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those who wants to use **regex** to define allowed characters, such as `[0-9]` (digits only), the following code does the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use File::Temp;                                       #  regex ─┐
use PadWalker qw /closed_over/;                       #         ↓

@{closed_over(\&File::Temp::_replace_XX)->{'@CHARS'}} = grep /[0-9]/, map{chr $_} 0..255;

print mktemp("digitsXXXX") . "\n";
```

Comment: **Example:** If we exclude spaces, the [regex charset for allowed filename characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794144/regular-expression-for-valid-filename) is `[\w\-.]`. Without the use or regex, this charset can be written as the array `('0'-'9','a'-'z','A'-'Z','_','-','.')`. Obviously both solutions are correct. It is coder's personal choice.

Answer (score 1):

Just for academic fun, you can override the [`_replace_XX`](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Temp/source/lib/File/Temp.pm#L615) function in the `File::Temp` package:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Temp;
use strict;
{   
    local *File::Temp::_replace_XX = sub { 
        my @CHARS = (qw/0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9/);
        # verbatim copy of the original 
        my ($path, $ignore) = @_;

        my $end = ( $] >= 5.006 ? "\\z" : "\\Z" );

        if ($ignore) {
            substr($path, 0, - $ignore) =~ s/X(?=X*$end)/$CHARS[ int( rand( @CHARS ) ) ]/ge;
        } else {
            $path =~ s/X(?=X*$end)/$CHARS[ int( rand( @CHARS ) ) ]/ge;
        }
        return $path;
    };
    print mktemp("digitsXXXX")."\n";
}
```

You can use the `B::Deparse` module so you don't have to manually replicate the code (and you don't want any other customization than changing the CHAR value)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Temp;
use B::Deparse;
use strict;
{   
    my $deparser = B::Deparse->new();
    my $code = $deparser->coderef2text(\&File::Temp::_replace_XX);

    local *File::Temp::_replace_XX = sub { 
        my @CHARS = 0..9;
        eval($code);
    };
    print mktemp("digitsXXXX")."\n";
}
```

Or you can use `PadWalker` (note this is not a core module) as [Grinnz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5848200/grinnz) suggested:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use File::Temp;
use PadWalker 'closed_over';

my $chars_ref = closed_over(\&File::Temp::_replace_XX)->{'@CHARS'};
@$chars_ref = 0..9;

print mktemp("digitsXXXX")."\n";
```